# Use mysqldb connect ipv6 server in Python

Tags: python, ipv6, mysql-python

I use mysqldb connect my db server, server'ip is ::1. Code like this:

```
MySQLdb.connect(host='::1',user='admin',passwd='123456',db='test')
```

but, I get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host '::1' (1)")
```

I want to know what should I do to allow mysqldb to support IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `::1` for the host, try use `localhost`.

If that doesn't work, your system likely does not support IPv6. You can find more information about IPv6 support [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ipv6-support.html).

Comment: thanks. this is my first time for ask question in Stack.